# Adding click listener to Google Maps v3 Compass (navigation control)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to figure out how i can attach a click event to a google maps v3 compass.

I have created a function that re-draws markers on a map and want this to be fired when the user click on the compass (arrows top left) of the google map.

I am working with google maps v3 and cant seem to find any way of doing this through the documentation.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did it work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

Click event of the compass is probably attached to the bounds_change event.  Essentially, you are changing the bounds of the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the center of the map changing:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
   // Call your function to redraw markers here.
});
```